# CircleCI e2e tests fail with Stripe script

Tags: selenium, stripe-payments, circleci

CircleCI tests are giving

`Too long with no output (exceeded 10m0s): context deadline exceeded`

This seems to be caused in our case by a newly introduced [Stripe script](https://stripe.com/docs/libraries/stripejs-esmodule) which stalls Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Following the GitHub link at the [top here](https://stripe.com/docs/libraries/stripejs-esmodule) led us to an awareness of [Advanced Fraud Detection](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js#disabling-advanced-fraud-detection-signals) and the ability to disable it. Loading the script via `pure` if tests don't hit relevant page or disabling Advanced Fraud Detection in testing env resolves timing out tests.

```js
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js/pure';

loadStripe.setLoadParameters({advancedFraudSignals: false});
const stripe = await loadStripe('pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx');
```

```html
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/?advancedFraudSignals=false"></script>
```

https://stripe.com/docs/disputes/prevention/advanced-fraud-detection#disabling-advanced-fraud-detection